# Get a segmentation fault through argv on purpose

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I want to write a small program, which, by user input through argv, gets a segmentation error. I am quite new to C but I think the following code does the job:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int bufferSize;
    char * buffer[100];
    unsigned int i;

    if (argc > 1) {
        bufferSize = atoi(argv[1]);
        for (i = 0; i < bufferSize; ++i)
            *( buffer + i ) = i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My idea is that the program intialize (?) a pointer to a buffer of a specific size. If the user then input a number larger then the buffer size it will write to uninitialized memory, hence get a seg. fault. Is this reasoning correct whatsoever?

Ps. When compiling,`I get a assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`warning, can someone maybe tell me why that happens? Thanks

Comment: Writing to unallocated memory is _undefined behavior_, so it may not actually crash. Or it will crash with a bus error, or something else may happen altogether.

Comment: If I were you, I'd just go for `*(char *)0 = 0;` - also note that this is UB, i. e. you can't expect **any** reasoning or explanation to the behavior of your program.

Comment: (On most systems) buffer is on the stack, so if you write past the end you are corrupting your stack, not writing to unallocated memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most traditional way to purposely get a segmentation fault, that I've seen, is to write to `NULL`, e.g. something like:

```
*((char *) NULL) = 0;
```

You can use a command line argument as a simple boolean value to see if this should be done or not.

Note that writing to `NULL` is not actually guaranteed to cause a crash, it's simply *undefined behavior* so basically anything could happen (including causing [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)).

The warning is because you have an array of pointers, and try to assign an integer to a pointer in the array.

Comment: Smart compilers might notice that this assignment causes undefined behaviour and instead insert an undefined instruction opcode.  I've had clang do it to me, for example.

Comment: OK, so basically, there is no guaranteed method to cause a segmentation error?

Comment: @Smajjk I haven't come across a platform where it doesn't crash with a segmentation fault (or similar), but it's not actually guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

`char * buffer[100];` is an array of pointer which points to some garbage locations by default.

Here `*( buffer + i ) = i;` you are trying to deference that area which doesn't belongs to you.

My guess is that, you wanted to create a buffer. so

`char buffer[100];` is enough.

Comment: Agree. But just a side note: I think *"dereference area which doesn't belong to you"* is not quite right, even with `char*[100]`. The statement `*( buffer + i ) = i;` will anyway write into i'th position array, thus overwriting i'th pointer, not dereferencing it. So the problem is only incompatibility of types: assigning `int` to `char*` item of array.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about writing to cause a segmentation fault. Reading is sufficient enough. You stand a better chance of causing a segfault if the buffer is on the heap. This application fairly reliably segfaults for negative inputs less than -10 for me.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    static const int array[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    int * const heapArray = malloc(sizeof(array));

    memcpy(heapArray,array,sizeof(array));

    const int index = atoi(argv[1]);

    printf("%i\n",heapArray[index]);

    free(heapArray);
    return 0;   
}
```

The problem is, the result of malloc() can be much much larger than the requested size for most systems. So even for large values it does not segfault, it just returns whatever happens to be there in memory.

```
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~$ ./segfault -5
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~$ ./segfault 11
0
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~$ ./segfault 100
0
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~$ ./segfault 100
0
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~$ ./segfault 1000
0
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~$ ./segfault 10000
0
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~$ ./segfault 100000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```